# ITM (Irish Transverse Coordinate) conversion to GPS for google maps Python3

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I don't know anything about coordinates. My problem is that I have a dataset that contains coordinates in the ITM format (Irish_X and Irish_Y). **I want to convert ITM coordinates into Google Maps readable ones**.

[image]

Online I found a library that may be useful but I don't know how to use and the documentation use a very specific jargon I'm not used to:
https://proj.org

I also commented in the same library gitHub repo looking for answer:
https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/1687

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The coordinates that you've listed are not in ITM but in Irish Grid instead. You can confirm that by insert them as ITM in the following "official" converter and you'll get an out of range error, https://gnss.osi.ie/new-converter/

Comment: Hi Luis, thanks for your comment, at the end I found another datasets with gps coordinates. Btw do you know how to convert them programmatically?

Comment: I'm giving the answer for ITM to WGS84 conversion, the title of this question. For Irish Grid better ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from ITM to WGS84 just call the `def itm2geo(x,y):` function as exemplified in the end of the code in the `Teste Values` section.

The first two functions (`arcmer` and `xy2geo`) are auxiliary functions and don't need to be explicitly called (they are called by `itm2geo(x,y)`

```
from math import *

############################################################################

# Meridian Arc

############################################################################

def arcmer(a,equad,lat1,lat2):

    b=a*sqrt(1-equad)

    n=(a-b)/(a+b)

    a0=1.+((n**2)/4.)+((n**4)/64.)

    a2=(3./2.)*(n-((n**3)/8.))

    a4=(15./16.)*((n**2)-((n**4)/4.))

    a6=(35./48.)*(n**3)



    s1=a/(1+n)*(a0*lat1-a2*sin(2.*lat1)+a4*sin(4.*lat1)-a6*sin(6.*lat1))

    s2=a/(1+n)*(a0*lat2-a2*sin(2.*lat2)+a4*sin(4.*lat2)-a6*sin(6.*lat2))

    return s2-s1

###############################################################################
#
# Transverse Mercator Inverse Projection
#
###############################################################################
def xy2geo(m,p,a,equad,lat0,lon0):

    lat0=radians(lat0)
    lon0=radians(lon0)

    sigma1=p

    fil=lat0+sigma1/(a*(1-equad))

    deltafi=1

    while deltafi > 0.0000000001:

        sigma2=arcmer(a,equad,lat0,fil)

        RO=a*(1-equad)/((1-equad*(sin(fil)**2))**(3./2.))

        deltafi=(sigma1-sigma2)/RO

        fil=fil+deltafi 


    N=a/sqrt(1-equad*(sin(fil))**2)

    RO=a*(1-equad)/((1-equad*(sin(fil)**2))**(3./2.))

    t=tan(fil)

    psi=N/RO

    lat=fil-(t/RO)*((m**2)/(2.*N))+(t/RO)*((m**4)/(24.*(N**3)))*(-4.*(psi**2)-9.*psi*(1.-t**2)+12.*(t**2))-(t/RO)*(m**6/(720.*(N**5)))*(8.*(psi**4)*(11.-24.*(t**2))-12.*(psi**3)*(21.-71.*(t**2))+15.*(psi**2)*(15.-98.*(t**2)+15.*(t**4))+180.*psi*(5.*(t**2)-3.*(t**4))-360.*(t**4))+(t/RO)*((m**8)/(40320.*(N**7)))*(1385.+3633.*(t**2)+4095.*(t**4)+1575.*(t**6))

    lon=(m/(N))-((m**3)/(6.*(N**3)))*(psi+2.*(t**2))+((m**5)/(120.*(N**5)))*(-4.*(psi**3)*(1.-6.*(t**2))+(psi**2)*(9.-68.*(t**2))+72.*psi*(t**2)+24.*(t**4))-((m**7)/(5040.*(N**7)))*(61.+662.*(t**2)+1320.*(t**4)+720.*(t**6))

    lon=lon0+lon/cos(fil)

    lat=degrees(lat)
    lon=degrees(lon)

    return lat,lon


#############################################################################

# Irish Transverse Mercator - Inverse

#############################################################################

def itm2geo(x,y):

    # GRS-80

    a = 6378137.

    equad =0.00669437999        

    # Natural Origin 

    lat0=53.5

    lon0=-8.

    k0=0.999820

    p = (y - 750000.) /k0

    m = (x - 600000.) /k0

    lat,lon = xy2geo(m,p,a,equad,lat0,lon0)

    return lat,lon

#############################################################################

# Test values 

#############################################################################             
#lat=53.5

#lon=-8.

test = itm2geo(600000.,750000.)

print ("latitude= %.16f" %test[0])
print ("longitude= %.16f" %test[1])
```

Comment: Wow man your code is sick! (In the good way). Thank you very much!

Comment: In case you are interested in the theory behind the implementation, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator:_Redfearn_series